# Fatal error when using REST client library in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, restful-url

I downloaded the Rest Client library from [here](http://getsparks.org/packages/restclient/versions/HEAD/show) and the Curl library for CodeIgniter from [here](http://getsparks.org/packages/curl/show).

I put both the libraries in a library folder and set them in auto load library.

Now when I try to run the following code:

```
class Api extends CI_Controller { 

function index()  
 {   
     $this->load->spark('restclient/2.1.0');
     $this->load->library('rest', array(  
           'server' => 'my rest service url', 
    ));
      $data = $this->rest->get();  
      echo '<pre>';
    print_r($data);
     }  
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Loader::spark() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/code/application/libraries/Rest.php on line 60
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to install spark. Look these links

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/easy-package-management-for-codeigniter-with-sparks/

http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/a-quick-look-at-sparks

Regards

iijb